# Is introducing yourself with "myself" completely wrong English?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, politeness, names

If I am introducing my name to a business client, which of these are correct:

```
 1. Hello! Myself John.
 2. Hello! My name is John.
 3. Hello! I am John.
 4. Hello! This is John.
 5. Hello! John.
```

Comment: Numbers 2 and 3 are used all the time. Number 5 only as an ell

Comment: #4 is used on the telephone.  (#2 & #3 are also acceptable for telephone)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numbers 2, 3, and 5 are standard ways to introduce yourself (if your name is John!).

Number 5 is less formal that the other two, and requires a particular kind of situation to be socially appropriate. It also requires certain pronunciation features and probably nonverbal behaviors to seem conventional.

Thus, numbers 2 and 3 are the safest and most standard of the list.

We cannot use "Myself John" to introduce ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers 2 and 3 are used all the time. You should learn those two forms first.

Number 5 would be comparatively rare, and it would represent either 2 or 3, with the other words elided (left out). It might be used when a person is meeting several people at one time. You can say #4 as well as #3 to identify yourself over the phone. A context in which #5 would be correct is possible, but so rare (and some might say far-fetched) that you can forget it. For normal daily situations, it would not be used.

Comment: #5 (eliding everything but your name) is actually somewhat common in the specific case of shaking hands in introduction, especially if you're going to include a title or other description: 
*offer hand to shake* "Hello! John Smith, head of project development." 
Or:
"Hi! John. I went to school with your brother."

Comment: Yes @MrTheWalrus I know that. And so it is comparatively rare compared with 2 and 3.